# KDEConnect: Duplicate Text Notifications

Tags: android, kde-plasma

What does it mean when you get a text on your phone, and instead of getting one notification on your desktop about it, you get dozens of identical ones that cover the screen?

I've checked out the KDEConnect troubleshooting sections, Googled and searched stackoverflow, but it's likely my searches for "kdeconnect duplicate notifications" are too naive to produce good results.

This happens on one workstation but not the other (same phone), so my best guess is that I Did Something to break it. Both workstations are the same Linux distribution. Both run the distribution's Plasma desktop and the distribution's version of kdeconnect (Fedora).

Any idea what I need to undo?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue. Certainly seems like KDEConnect's fault, but I suppose it could be the nofication system's fault. Maybe it's supposed to debounce extra messages. I have a very different setup than you - I'm on [sway](https://github.com/swaywm/sway) with [mako](https://github.com/emersion/mako) for notifications. I'm using the latest KDEConnect from FDroid on LineageOS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to go into the app on your phone, go to Plugin Settings, go to Notification Sync settings, and uncheck your messaging app.

I had the exact same problem, and I just figured it out.

It is giving you 2 notifications. 1 for it being a notification, and another for being an SMS because you have Send SMS enabled.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, I counted. It's giving me 62 notifications of the same event. For example, if my phone rings, I get 62 messages telling me the phone number.

Comment: If it's an SMS, then I get 62 popups, each with a "reply" button. That's what I mean when I say they cover the screen.

Comment: This answer is wrong, you get sms and call notification duplicate even if you don't forward application's specific notification. The problem still exist as described in 2022

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with whatsapp notifications and followed the above but disabled KDE Connect instead of whatsapp. That worked out nice

Comment: I had my hopes up but sadly this didn't work for me. I still get notifications covering the whole screen as Alan Schmidt said.